# Bug? G-T-E forgot all of my autosaving / unsaved drafts, how do I recover them?

Tags: kde, gnome-text-editor

Setup: KUbuntu 22.04. Have installed Gnome Text Editor (sadly I cannot find a KDE native with what to me is basics) -- version 42.2.

Situation: I had G-T-E set to auto-restore files on restart. And, normally, it works fine. But up until now, my restarting it was always by "no file" just starting it up -- it restored all of my in-progress drafts, which was good -- auto saving, keeping things alive.

Today, I was downloading a text file in chromium. Never mind the bleep of "I won't display a text file in a tab, I force you to open through another app". I choose the G-T-E because that's what I've found works best.

G-T-E opened with *only this one file*.

All my edits in progress, all my drafts, gone.

Nor could I find any way to undo this / recover. Trying to close this file that was started from Chromium's open with another program, and then start G-T-E from normal menu launch ... resulted in the same single file.

So:
1, Is there a way to find my unsaved, unnamed drafts (What on mac would be the Untitled nnn.txt files),
2, is there a way to find the unsaved edits to files (the auto-saved edits in progress that got saved to some holding directory rather than to the real files in the file system)?

And 3, this apparent bug of "I'll throw away all information about your previous editing state because you started me differently" -- is someone else willing to confirm this is a bug, and how can this be fixed?

Full about information:

```
Text Editor (42.2)

GLib: 2.72.4 (2.72.1)
GTK: 4.6.9 (4.6.5)
GtkSourceView: 5.4.1 (5.4.1)
Libadwaita: 1.1.7 (1.1.0)
Enchant2: 2.3.2

gtk-theme-name: Adwaita-empty
GTK_THEME: unset

org.gnome.TextEditor restore-session = true
org.gnome.TextEditor recolor-window = true
org.gnome.TextEditor show-map = false
org.gnome.TextEditor custom-font = 'Comic Sans MS 16' [default='Monospace 11']
org.gnome.TextEditor show-line-numbers = false
org.gnome.TextEditor style-scheme = 'classic' [default='Adwaita']
org.gnome.TextEditor wrap-text = true
org.gnome.TextEditor style-variant = 'light' [default='follow']
org.gnome.TextEditor indent-style = 'tab'
org.gnome.TextEditor show-right-margin = false
org.gnome.TextEditor spellcheck = true
org.gnome.TextEditor auto-indent = true
org.gnome.TextEditor use-system-font = false [default=true]
org.gnome.TextEditor keybindings = 'default'
org.gnome.TextEditor highlight-current-line = false
org.gnome.TextEditor last-save-directory = 'file:///media/user/Transfer/New%20files/Strange%20Online' [default='']
org.gnome.TextEditor auto-save-delay = uint32 3
org.gnome.TextEditor discover-settings = true
org.gnome.TextEditor enable-snippets = false
org.gnome.TextEditor line-height = 1.2
org.gnome.TextEditor indent-width = -1
org.gnome.TextEditor show-grid = false
org.gnome.TextEditor draw-spaces = @as []
org.gnome.TextEditor right-margin-position = uint32 76 [default=uint32 80]
org.gnome.TextEditor tab-width = uint32 8
```

Other questions (since they really don't seem documented):
1, What is adwaita? What is classic? How do I switch them / would I want to / where is any of this documented?
2, How do I even turn on line numbers? How do I turn them on/off on a per-window/tab/file basis?
3, Why can't I have (Or, how do I enable this?) the system  font being used? Why do I have to change fonts in every program if they have a "use system font" option hidden off somewhere anyways???

What I consider basics (if anyone knows of a KDE interface native that does these, please tell me):
1, autosave of the workstate in progress (can restore all unsaved drafts/edits),
2, happy to work with a non-monospace font or odd size by default,
3, does not want to force formatted text / styles into the document (how it is displayed on-screen is NOT the same as what is in the file -- that I need a non-blocky font, large size, is a *display* issue, not a file content issue)
4, gives me full control over preferences instead of just "here's a few images with a few preset colors, this is all the control you get".
5, does not have it's own internal window manager that ignores the system behavior (nb: G-T-E breaks this in a KDE system. Yes I'm aware that it behaves properly in a gnome system, but why the bleep is any of this in the application itself and not in a localization library that is custom for the end system? i.e. -- why is KDE unable to use a compatibility library to make gnome applications behave/display like KDE applications? Why isn't that a system level thing entirely?)